# Динамическое добавление скрипта в iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Есть iframe, генерирующийся динамически. Что в нём - я не знаю, но доступ к нему через contentWindow есть. Подскажите пожалуйста, как извне добавить туда скрипт так, чтобы он выполнился первее всех остальных там уже находящихся.

P.S. Чтоб было понятно - скрипт изменяет код функции console.log();

Собственно динамическая генерация iframe:

```
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.setAttribute("SRC", [*ссылка на frame*]);
document.body.appendChild(frame);
//далее попытки запихнуть туда свой собственный скрипт
```

Comment: Что значит " генерирующийся динамически"? "Чтоб было понятно" - добавьте код.

Comment: @xelanimed, исходник добавлен)

Comment: @ИльяКолдунов А ваш `iframe` получает данные из другого домена?

Comment: даже если речь идет о том же домене, засунуть во фрэйм снаружи свой скрипт до любого другого, приходящего с фрэймом, - маловероятно. Нет подходящего события.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено. В сторону установки скриптов в DOM не стоило и копать - дерево недоступно пока полностью не выполнятся другие скрипты. Достаточно сразу после установки iframe выполнить свой код в контексте этого iframe.
Вот, как переопределить console.log в iframe:

```
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.setAttribute("SRC", [*ссылка на frame*]);
document.body.appendChild(frame);

var bounding = console.log.bind(frame.contentWindow.console);
frame.contentWindow.console.log = function(message)
{
    bounding(message);
    //что-то нужное
}
```

Comment: Как то не уверен что он будет работать самым первым, вы вопросе сказали что так хотите верно?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, но оно срабатывает первее всех (доказано практикой). Причём делает оно это пока страница загружается.

Comment: знаю, я обяснил в ответе почему это так

Answer (score 1):

Это пример кода показывает когда завершается загрузка вашего `iframe`.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var str='<iframe id="theiframe" class="iframe-class" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZhHMqAUbgKQ"></iframe>';
    $(document.body).append(str);
   });
   
   $('iframe').ready(function(){
    $('#theiframe').on("load", function() {
     console.log('iframe loaded');
    });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

> Но если домен в `iframe` не тот, то доступ к DOM невозможен, и вы все ровно ни как не сможете манипулировать с `DOM iframe`.
>
> Получите ошибку доступа. Подробно о совмесном использовании ресурсов разных
>   источников можете прочитать [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Обновляю ответ после комментария на ответ:

Если доступ к `iframe` есть то взять элементы `DOM iframe` можно так.

```
$("#theiframe").contents().find("#simple_elem")
```

Но невозможно сделать так что бы ваш скрипт работал самым первым, потому что скрипты в нем начнут работать как только браузер загрузит их в `DOM` то есть все ровно они будут работать первым. До добавления вашего скрипта.

Comment: Доступ к iframe есть. Да, он на этом домене. @RazmikGalstyan этот код выполнится после полной загрузки iframe - несмотря на то, что jQuery не знаю и недолюбливаю, вижу событие onload. Все скрипты работают до события onload(