# Не открывается сайт в Iframe, содержимое ошибки внутри

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

Вот такие выходят ошибки, вроде как сайт должен располагаться на одном домене, а обойти или поставить какую то настройку нельзя?

неужели file_get_contents теперь использовать?

```
Refused to display 'http://oдругой сайт/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

оба сайта на одном хостинге.

Эта шутка возможно на сервере включена, может такое быть?

```html
Ниже мой фрэйм
<iframe frameborder="0" height="200px" scrolling="no" src="http://oren-teplo.ru/" width="100%"></iframe> а этот рабочий
<iframe frameborder="0" height="200px" scrolling="no" src="http://rc-56.ru/" width="100%"></iframe> но на данном форму обба не отображатся скорее всего настройка тоже какая то здесь выставлена
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

соджержимое .htaccess

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 //index.php

# Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
<Files favicon.ico>
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php
# but the following cannot be changed at runtime.

# PHP 4, Apache 1.
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 4, Apache 2.
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  # Do not cache dynamically generated pages.
  ExpiresByType text/html A1
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # adapt and uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment and adapt the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  RewriteBase /
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# $Id: .htaccess.in,v 1.1.1.1 2008/10/02 09:13:43 ilobachev Exp $
```

Comment: Вместо file_get_contents лушче посмотрите на [curl](http://www.php.su/lessons/?lesson_11)

Comment: Так и должно быть, посмотрите тут, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675393/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-iframe/677513#677513

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan так мне не нужно скрипт выполнять, мне просто нужно загрузить один сайт в другом. а он не грузится. просто фрейм пуст

Comment: Ну тогда дай пример кода как ты это делаешь, а то нужно гадать

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan отредактировал

Comment: как не отображается ? я скинул у себя просто в `html` и все нормально отображает

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, первый сайт не отображается прикрепил скрин в вопрос

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов другой сайт в `iframe` Показывает, а в том задано в `htaccess` примерно такое `Header set X-Frame-Options DENY`. И это блокирует загрузку сайта в `iframe`.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan дополнил вопрос, содержимым htaccess

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов это никак вы не можете исправить, это не от `htaccess`֊а вашего сайта, а того сайта который вы загружаете в `iframe`.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, это htaccess загружаемого сайта оба мои)
и содержимое файлов идентичное

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов и оба на одном и том же сервере? Оба сайта которые вы загружате в `iframe`

Comment: Задайте в `htaccess` вот это, может поможет, `Header set X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM URL

Header set X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM URL

X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM URL`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60820/discussion-between---and-razmik-galstyan).

Answer (score 4):

`X-Frame-Options` параметр задется в настройках `nginx` и его можно менять для сайта в `.htaccess`, Если хотите именно для конкретного сайта дать доступ то можете в `htaccess` написать так.

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN 
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM example.com
```

Где `example.com` имя сайта для которого открываете доступ.

Подробно можете прочитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

Answer (score 0):

Проверил сервер, дело было не в нем, настройка была в ядре Drupal, на этой системе управления и были построены сайты, версия ядра разная, в старой версии такой проблемы не было, в новой решили добавить, видимо, в целях безопасности.
Обойти эту штуку можно было выключив в файле

```
/includes/common.inc
```

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN