# Blocked a frame with origin.... Не могу избежать

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, blocks

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://sergeimorozov.com/" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Пытаюсь обратиться к своему же домену, http://desctopimage.ru/ - но вот такая вот ситуация, там и тут стоит WP, самый простой без всяких особенностей, почти со стандартным шаблоном.

Вопрос, как сделать ему по домену разрешение, то есть вообще что сделать чтобы избежать для себя самого этой блокировки? Условие, что оба мои - то есть если надо я могу вообще все...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681888/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%B2-iframe-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8/681946#681946

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса.

Comment: Что-то через header в php все равно не помогло...