# Отслеживание событий во фрейме на другом домене

Tags: javascript, http, iframe

На страничке подключен фрейм.

Отслеживаю событие onClick по фрейму и изменяю его размеры:

```
document.getElementById('widget_iframe').onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("widget_iframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById('chat_header').onclick = function() {
    $('#widget_chat').animate({height: 400, width: 300}, 200);
  }

      document.getElementById("widget_iframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById('chat_header_full').onclick = function() {
    $('#widget_chat').animate({height: 40, width: 330}, 200);
  }
}
```

На одном домене все работает, при подключении iframe на другом домене - получаю ошибку (работа по http, не https):

> Uncaught DOMException: 
>   Blocked a frame with origin "http://main.domen" from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame.
>   at HTMLIFrameElement.document.getElementById.onload

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно обойти это ограничение?

Comment: Так и должно быть, это нельзя сделать на для разных доменов.

Comment: Другой домен ваш?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681888/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%B2-iframe-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8/681946#681946

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!
Другой домен так же мой, но в итоге виджет будет на чужом домене, поэтому хотел проблему выявить на более раннем этапе.

Comment: Если  у вас нет доступа к чужому домену, что бы изменить все это, то что в ответе было написано, то ни как не получится задуманное.

Comment: Понял, еще раз спасибо!